# Validate autosuggest selected by user

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I am using Geonames API to autocomplete an address field in my form. It is of the format "City,State,Country". Sometimes it takes time for the suggestions to load, so the user enters "City" and moves to next field. Moreover, there are spelling mistakes in the city names. I want to force the user to select a value from autocomplete values. How can this be achieved in PHP and Jquery?

Comment: i am doing an explode in php and checking there are 3 parts. But i do not want it on server side, i want to force user to select one of the suggested values.

Comment: use jqueryui's autocomplete(http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)